# Add Objective C SDK into Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, ads

I'm working in a xamarin.forms app and I really like it! Just a problem, now I'm trying to add a sdk of ad partners called IronSource (SupersonicAds), but I don't know how to, because is code in objective C.

There is any possibility to integrate it in xamarin.forms?

My objective is integrate an Offerwall, if anyone made it would be really helpful to know how to.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Xamarin binding library.  This will create a C# wrapper around a native iOS Obj-C library.

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/